# Duplicate error message when validating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-models, duplication

How is it possible that the model validation errors messages are getting duplicated in ruby on rails application?

Comment: The reasons could be many and various I suspect. It would be worth giving more of an example of what you are doing, what your validation messages are and under what circumstances you are seeing the duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you are calling `valid?` in addition to `save`?

Answer (score 7):

One area where I have found that duplication of validation error message occurs is when using plugins like Authlogic or Clearance which handle authentication. Often they have their own validations which also run alongside your validations inside your models. Carefully looking at the API and RDoc for these plugins will reveal how to suppress these messages or customise them.

Hope that helps.